# Pigeonhole's Principle - set of nine distinct points

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

The question is "Let $(x_i , y_i , z_i ), i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,$ be a set of nine distinct points with integer coordinates in $xyz$-space. Show
that the midpoint of at least one pair of these points has
integer coordinates."

Wouldn't the set
${(3,3,1),(2,2,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,3),(2,2,4),(2,2,5),(2,2,6),(2,2,7), (2,2,8)} $
be a counterexample to the theorem the exercise asks to find?

Thank you!

Comment: Are we to guess what the missing points in your set are?  Anyway, in your list $(2,2,2)$ and $(2,2,4)$ work.

Comment: In any case, we want each of the three coordinates to match in parity.  There are $8$ ways to set the parities, so...

Comment: An edit has been made changing $(xi, yi, zi)$ to $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$. Which is correct? In the original version, assuming $x$, $y$ and $z$ are supposed to be integers, you can't have both $(3,3,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ within your set, since in both cases $i=1$. After the edit, you can.

Comment: The second version is the correct one @HSN

Comment: @lulu thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint between $(2,2,1)$ and $(2,2,3)$ has integer coordinates.  Anyway, the parity - pigeonhole principle argument given earlier is correct.